# Ajax timeout when executing a command in backend

Tags: ajax, timeout

I am using $.ajax method to get data from server but facing 'connection Timed out error 504'.

My application is web application deployed on Apache-Tomcat server.In the back end I run a command using "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)"

The command is running a hadoop command . Even after the error the command runs successfully and creates the output file . 
The entire process takes about 3 minutes

I have done following things to solve this issue-

```
            1.Modified $.ajax  keeping timeout: 300000(ms)



            2.Modified session timout in <Project>/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

            <session-config>

                            <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>

            </session-config>



            3.Modified server.xml  for infinite timout limit  apache-tomcat-7.0.53/home/hduser/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf                

                            <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

           connectionTimeout="-1"

           redirectPort="8443" />



            4.Modified web.xml for infinite timeout limit   apache-tomcat-7.0.53/home/hduser/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/conf



              <session-config>

    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>

</session-config>
```

Still I am getting 'connection Timed out error 504'.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to break a long time task into 2 parts for online application:

1. Trigger the task, and return a unique task id intermediately.
2. Retrieve result later with the task id.

Comment: Is that the only option I have . There is no option to change the time out error. Changing the implementation right now seems to be difficult. Also do you mean to continuously poll with the task id to check the if the task is completed ??

Comment: I don't mean "continuousely poll", maybe Push works for you (such as Comet or WebSocket)

Comment: Feng I really appreciate your help . I agree the ideal solution would be to use Push but currently I need a quick fix . Also what would be the root cause for it ? I am looking more on the lines of changing some configuration to make it wait longer before it timesout

Comment: It seems there is a proxy server between your application server and clients. Maybe you should also change configuration of the proxy server to extend its timeout value.

Comment: About proxy timeout value, see more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ja/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout

Comment: Thanks Feng , proxy was the culprit . For now I bypassed the proxy as my server was local and in the same network.